How to a pixel from one GeoTIFF onto another using proj
I have two GeoTIFF rasters, each with their own proj4 string.  I need to take all of the pixels from one raster, and map it onto the other.  Some of the pixels may not actually land on the other, but in that case they should simply have values less than 0, or greater than the resolution.
What I have currently attempted is:
PJ_CONTEXT* ctx = proj_context_create();
PJ* psPJ = proj_create_crs_to_crs(ctx, sourceProjStr.c_str(), targetProjStr.c_str(), NULL);

// Loop over all pixels from source image:
for (size_t i = 0; i < source.resolution.x; ++i) {
    for (size_t j = 0; j < source.resolution.y; ++j) {
        // Convert from source pixel-space to the source model-space:
        PJ_COORD coord;
        coord.xyzt.x = (static_cast<double>(i) * source.pixelScale[0]) + source.modelTiePoint[0];
        coord.xyzt.y = (static_cast<double>(j) * (-1 * source.pixelScale[1])) + source.modelTiePoint[1];
        coord.xyzt.z = 0;
        coord.xyzt.t = 0;

        // Perform transformation (source model-space to target model-space):
        coord = proj_trans(psPJ, PJ_FWD, coord);

        // Convert from target model-space to target pixel-space: 
        double x = (coord.xyzt.x - target.modelTiePoint[0]) / target.pixelScale[0];
        double y = (coord.xyzt.y - target.modelTiePoint[1]) / (-1 * target.pixelScale[1]);

        // Ignore if projected point does not lie within the target raster image:
        if (x < 0 || y < 0) {
            continue;
        }
        if (x >= target.resolution.x || y >= target.resolution.y) {
            continue;
        }

        // Do something with the found to be overlapping pixel coordinates
    };
}

proj_destroy(psPJ);
proj_context_destroy(ctx);

This sometimes seems to work, however other times it does not.  It seems to fail when the modelTiePoint of the target and source rasters do not match (even if they agree on lon_0 model-space coordinate).
I need this to work automatically, for any two GeoTIFFs regardless of their projection.

Different folks have different expectations of "automatically". Getting this working for arbitrary inputs is on the far edge of possible and probably requires a lot more code than you have here.

I can assume that the GeoTIFFs actually belong to the same celestial body with the same reference ellipsoid, and agree on the same reference system.  I should have mentioned that (the data-sets I work with are also primarily not of the Earth).
All of the information I need appears to be there.  My problem is when, say, one tif has a negative model-tie-point with lon_0 = 180, while another tif as a 0 model-tie-point and a lon_0 = 0.  Both agree that lon_0 is in the same model-space location, but I am unsure how to "align" them
